# Conditional ON in a stored procedure with OPENJSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that inserts data into a table from an API string that is passed to the `OPENJSON` function. This API though, sometimes renders a different key name according to the length of the value.

For instance:

```
{
  {
   "id":"1",
   "shortName": Alex
  },
   "id":"2",
   "longName": Alexander
  }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspAddToTable 
    @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (id, name)
        SELECT id, name 
        FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
        WITH 
            (id integer '$.id',
             name varchar(100) '$.shortName' /* here how do I do: OR '$.longName' if '$.shortName' does not exist */
            ) tbl
```

Is this possible in the stored procedure to take one or the other key value name depending if it can't find the default `shortName` to `longName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do, instead, is return *both* columns in your `OPENJSON` call, and then use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` in your `SELECT` to return the non-`NULL` value:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspAddToTable @json nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (id,name)
    SELECT id,
           ISNULL(shortName,longName)
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
            WITH (id int,
                  shortName varchar(100),
                  longName varchar(100)) OJ;
END;
```

I *assume* here that one of the other will be `NULL` or that `shortName` is the "prioritised" value.

Comment: Yes shortName, would be the prioritized key name.

Comment: No, i'm not adding a new column to your table, @AnalyzingTasks , I'm just returning *both* `shortName` *and* `LongName` from your JSON, and then in the `SELECT` if the value of `shortName` is `NULL` then the value of `longName` is returned instead.

Comment: Sorry , I just saw the ISNULL on the SELECT statement. @Larnu

So would it be:

`WITH( id int, '$.id', shortName varchar(100) '$.shortName', longName varchar(100) '$.longName')`

Comment: The `WITH` clause is already in the above SQL, @AnalyzingTasks ...

Comment: So the conditionals can be applied in the SELECT part of it, ok I think that may work, I'll test and confirm, thank you! @Larnu